# How the Galactic objects are moving?

Tags: galaxy, speed, movement

We know that the Galaxies are moving very fast, not only the Galaxies other known and unknown objects in the universe, are moving. But when it was started where is the starting point, and how it move with so much speed. Is there any theory on that  ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The theory you want is (probably) [the FLRW metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations).